# Copy string (hexadecimal format) to ulong in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I need to copy elements of a string which are in hexadecimal format to ulong.

Example:

```
string s = "0x4E45565251554954";     // already in hex format

ulong t;     // this ulong should be t=0x4E45565251554954.
```

Comment: `0x..` is just a [hexadecimal representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal). Not the real value. Your `t` will be `5640009019903265108` when you parse it.

Comment: Yes, exactly. How would I get a ulong with value=0x4E45565251554954?

Comment: 0x simply means that the base of the number in value, which must be 16.

Comment: So how do I convert a string like "Helloworld" to hex value stored in ulong? When I try it with ulong.Parse method, it throws System.FormatException.

Comment: The input value you've shown is a hexadecimal representation of a number; you say you want to parse that into the underlying number. You then want that number represented as a hexadecimal number somewhere else, so that will require a suitable format when you output it. Show us where & how you want to use it, as I suspect that's where your problem lies.

Comment: I want to encrypt string like "helloworld" using DES algorithm. Now I've got an already implemented method which takes message input in ulong type having hex values. So far I've been able to convert a normal text string in to hexadecimal string which I mentioned as input. I want that hex string to be ulong.

Comment: If you post your code for conversion you might get more responses.

Answer (score 5):

Or:

```
string s = "0x4E45565251554954";
ulong t = Convert.ToUInt64(s, 16);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some pointers... I'm afraid the conversion isn't as simple as you might hope...

[Taken from here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3zk09b81%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

i.e. is it a signed or unsigned value?

"When performing binary operations or numeric conversions, it is always the responsibility of the developer to verify that a method or operator is using the appropriate numeric representation to interpret a particular value. The following example illustrates one technique for ensuring that the method does not inappropriately use binary representation to interpret a value that uses two's complement representation when converting a hexadecimal string to a UInt64 value. The example determines whether a value represents a signed or an unsigned integer while it is converting that value to its string representation. When the example converts the value to a UInt64 value, it checks whether the original value was a signed integer. If so, and if its high-order bit is set (which indicates that the original value was negative), the method throws an exception. "

```
// Create a negative hexadecimal value out of range of the UInt64 type. 
long sourceNumber = Int64.MinValue;
bool isSigned = Math.Sign((long)sourceNumber.GetType().GetField("MinValue").GetValue(null)) == -1;
string value = Convert.ToString(sourceNumber, 16);
UInt64 targetNumber;
try
{
   targetNumber = Convert.ToUInt64(value, 16);
   if (isSigned && ((targetNumber & 0x8000000000000000) != 0))
      throw new OverflowException();
   else 
      Console.WriteLine("0x{0} converts to {1}.", value, targetNumber);
}
catch (OverflowException)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '0x{0}' to an unsigned long integer.", 
                 value);
} 

// Displays the following to the console: 
//    Unable to convert '0x8000000000000000' to an unsigned long integer.
```

The following example attempts to interpret each element in an array of numeric strings as a hexadecimal value and to convert it to an unsigned long integer.

```
public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string[] hexStrings = { "80000000", "0FFFFFFF", "F0000000", "00A3000", "D", 
                          "-13", "9AC61", "GAD", "FFFFFFFFFF" };

      foreach (string hexString in hexStrings)
      {
         Console.Write("{0,-12}  -->  ", hexString);
         try {
            uint number = Convert.ToUInt32(hexString, 16);
            Console.WriteLine("{0,18:N0}", number);
         }
         catch (FormatException) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,18}", "Bad Format");
         }   
         catch (OverflowException)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,18}", "Numeric Overflow");
         }   
         catch (ArgumentException) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,18}", "Invalid in Base 16");
         }
      }                                            
   }
}
// The example displays the following output: 
//       80000000      -->       2,147,483,648 
//       0FFFFFFF      -->         268,435,455 
//       F0000000      -->       4,026,531,840 
//       00A3000       -->             667,648 
//       D             -->                  13 
//       -13           -->  Invalid in Base 16 
//       9AC61         -->             633,953 
//       GAD           -->          Bad Format 
//       FFFFFFFFFF    -->    Numeric Overflow
```